# How do I configure required columns on Wiki pages?

Tags: column, wiki

In a SharePoint 2010 Wiki page library, if I add metadata columns to the page library, something like "Category" and make it a required column.  When I go and create a new Wiki Page in that library I'm never prompted to enter the metadata.

In 2007 the metadata columns always showed at the bottom of the Wiki Page which wasn't great but now in 2010 I never get prompted to input the metadata unless I go back to the library and "Edit Properties".

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you should enable the option to require pages to be checked out before editing them.  Then, when a user checks-in a new page, it will prompt them to complete the fields before it will let them check it in.